# JavaFX ColorPicker customizable via CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm struggling with javafx as a starter. I am trying to find the  structure of a color picker that is modifiable with css.

Until now i've found that a colorpicker has a label child that can be customizable all fine.
Now what i want is to customize the background of the expanded colorpicker menu (i dont know the name of that):

[image]

I tried .color-picker * {
-fx-background-color: black
}
and worked like a charm, but i don't want to do a barbaric thing like this. I'm sure the exact structure of it has to be somewhere so i can modify it with CSS.

Looked into javafx css reference already, but found nothing relevant about this!

P.S: also, i would like ot know if it's possible to remove the "Custom Color..." dialog completely from the colorpicker somehow.

Comment: Not documented, as far as I know, but try `color-palette-region` and/or `color-picker-grid`.

Comment: Too bad it's not documented... thanks for the information. Any other opinions?

Comment: Well I found those style classes by looking at the implementation. If they aren't working for you then you might be able to find something that does by looking at the implementation yourself. There's also [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) which may help inspect the scene graph.