# Is the text label of a ColorPicker in Javafx customizable?

Tags: java, css, javafx

Let me be clear that I am *not* trying to use the output of a ColorPicker with this question. I figured out how to do that. I'm just trying to modify it.

By default, the ColorPicker has a white-ish background with a black-ish text color.

The only thing that isn't default about this is the fact that I've assigned the starting color to be black.

[image]

Perusing the javadocs has led me to finding that I can change the borders and the background of the ColorPicker just fine:

```
Color contrast = color.invert();

colorPicker.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(contrast, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
colorPicker.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(color, null, null)));
```

That gets you the following:

Moved onto a black background so you can see the white border.

[image]

Questions like these ([JavaFX ColorPicker customizable via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792858/javafx-colorpicker-customizable-via-css)) that have images of people having done this before have led me to believe that this is possible. Perhaps they are dated (I'm using javafx v21). However, despite my best efforts, I haven't manage to accomplish something similar to this using either built-in methods or css through `colorPicker.setStyle()`. I've tried most of what I can think of *aside from* making an entire css stylesheet, which I think is overkill (which is my way of implying that I have no idea how to do that, so if you have suggestions for tutorials on how to create css stylesheets, I would appreciate them, since most of the ones I've found talk about using css once you've set it up instead of how to integrate it into a Java project, which is the part I need a tutorial on because picking up a language is not what I'm confused about with these things).

Comment: Study [modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).   [css reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG).  Then practice (a lot).  There is no shortcut. CSS in JavaFX 21 and 8 is almost identical, as long as it uses modena, it is not outdated and tutorials and rules will still apply.

Comment: Prefer style sheets over coded or inline styles almost always.

Comment: What specifically does not work when you use an external style sheet?

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used a style sheet. I've just done everything short of that. I was just hoping to setup the framework of what I'm working on in Java alone before learning CSS to do so. I recognize why it would be better, I've simply never used it before. It seems like I have to, though, because now this is gonna bug me.

Answer (score 3):

The style class for the label is `color-picker-label`. You can set the desired color of the label in the css file as below:

```
.color-picker .color-picker-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
}
```

However, if you are looking to set these colors dynamically, you can create a variable in css for the colors you want. And only update these variables in progrom using `setStyle()`.

For demonstration purpose, you can check the below demo code, that updates the background and foreground color of the color picker based on the value it has. I hope this can provide you some direction.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColorPickerDemo extends Application {
    // YOu can keep the below code in the css file also.
    public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
                    .color-picker{
                        -fx-cp-background: #000000;
                        -fx-cp-foreground: #FFFFFF;
                        -fx-background-color: -fx-cp-background;
                        -fx-border-color: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    
                    .color-picker .color-picker-label {
                        -fx-text-fill: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    
                    .color-picker .picker-color-rect{
                        -fx-stroke: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
        colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((obs, old, color) -> {
            String bg = toHexString(color);
            String contrast = toHexString(color.invert());
            colorPicker.setStyle("-fx-cp-background:" + bg + ";-fx-cp-foreground:" + contrast + ";");
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(colorPicker);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ColorPicker");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // The below code is picked from StackOverflow
    public String toHexString(Color value) {
        return "#" + (format(value.getRed()) + format(value.getGreen()) + format(value.getBlue()) + format(value.getOpacity()))
                .toUpperCase();
    }

    private String format(double val) {
        String in = Integer.toHexString((int) Math.round(val * 255));
        return in.length() == 1 ? "0" + in : in;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Sai. Thanks for the thoughtful response. However, this is one of the things that I've tried that did not work. Perhaps there's an issue with how I'm formatting my multi-line setStyle() arg. Disregarding creating a style sheet (as I mentioned, I don't know how), the following does not do anything for me:
`colorPicker.setStyle(""".color-picker .color-picker-label {-fx-text-fill: #ffffff;}""");` The fact that this is not working for me is where most of my confusion is coming from.

Comment: @GeorgeEconomou, the code you posted in the comments can NOT work. The method setStyle() applies Inline CSS. You MUST use CSS from a css file to style components inside a component (label inside colorpicker).

Comment: As mentioned by @DavidWeber, the multi line text is not for setStyle. It is to set as a style sheet itself. In setStyle you can only set the attributes only(like -fx-background-color, -fx-fill,.etc). Not the style classes itself..

Comment: @GeorgeEconomou Inline styles can only contain CSS *rules*, which are `;`-delimited lists of property-value pairs. They cannot contain *selectors*, such as `.color-picker .color-picker-label`, which determine the elements to which the rules are applied. For inline styles, the rules are applied to the node on which `setStyle(…)` is invoked (and descendants, for properties which are inherited). Since you don’t have a Java reference to the label,  you need an external style sheet here.

Comment: Thank you, all three of you. That makes sense now, especially in context with Sai's answer. It bothers me that the library doesn't have this functionality by default, but it's not as though having a CSS style sheet isn't a better way to be doing this to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

Just a summary of my comment above.

**Explanation:**

Why does your way not work? I hope you are familiar with FXML or at least HTML. There are standalone tags (components) like label or div (HTML), but there are also tags like Colorpicker or media (HTML), which are a summary of many other tags.

A Colorpicker has a Label component inside it (in HTML you would say in its Shadow Dom).

With setStyle() you can only apply CSS to the root element itself (e.g. Colorpicker), but NOT to their child elements (Label).

So you have to create a CSS file in which you CAN specify the styling of child elements.

This `.color-picker{...}` means "put style on ColorPicker.

This  `.color-picker .color-picker-label {...}` means "put style on all ColorPickerLabels inside ColorPicker".

**Solution:**

Step 1: Create a **CSS FILE** as String

```
public static final String CSS = "data:text/css," + // language=CSS
            """
                    .color-picker{
                        -fx-cp-background: #000000;
                        -fx-cp-foreground: #FFFFFF;
                        -fx-background-color: -fx-cp-background;
                        -fx-border-color: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    
                    .color-picker .color-picker-label {
                        -fx-text-fill: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    
                    .color-picker .picker-color-rect{
                        -fx-stroke: -fx-cp-foreground;
                    }
                    """;
```

Step 2: Add the CSS FILE to your Scene

`scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS)`;

Note:

This `"data:text/css,"` must be the first part of your CSS String. Do not forget it!

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I know how these languages work, I'm just neither *comfortable* with them, nor have I used CSS, specifically, hence why I wanted to setup my Java code before going back and taking care of this. I could do it with a multi-line string the way you have, but at this point, I may as well just figure out how to make a style sheet, anyway.